# Kubernetes RBAC: permissions mismatching

Tags: kubernetes

I'm facing with next issue. I'm requesting to kubernetes whether I'm able to make some operation:

```
$ kubectl auth can-i list secrets --namespace iotdevadm
no - no RBAC policy matched
```

Above, I'm asking for listing secrets. According to response, I'm not able to do that.

However:

```
$ kubectl get secrets
NAME                              TYPE                                  DATA   AGE
builder-dockercfg-9m9rf           kubernetes.io/dockercfg               1      23h
builder-token-6xxdn               kubernetes.io/service-account-token   4      23h
builder-token-qc7q7               kubernetes.io/service-account-token   4      23h
default-dockercfg-qs7sj           kubernetes.io/dockercfg               1      23h
default-token-n4lpw               kubernetes.io/service-account-token   4      23h
default-token-n7rhh               kubernetes.io/service-account-token   4      23h
deployer-dockercfg-nhnps          kubernetes.io/dockercfg               1      23h
deployer-token-5rkb6              kubernetes.io/service-account-token   4      23h
deployer-token-v85wp              kubernetes.io/service-account-token   4      23h
istio.builder                     istio.io/key-and-cert                 3      23h
istio.default                     istio.io/key-and-cert                 3      23h
istio.deployer                    istio.io/key-and-cert                 3      23h
istio.kafka                       istio.io/key-and-cert                 3      16h
istio.zeppelin                    istio.io/key-and-cert                 3      18h
kafka-dockercfg-whltw             kubernetes.io/dockercfg               1      16h
kafka-token-crrxt                 kubernetes.io/service-account-token   4      16h
kafka-token-j5dgd                 kubernetes.io/service-account-token   4      16h
sh.helm.release.v1.kafka.v1       helm.sh/release.v1                    1      16h
sh.helm.release.v1.spark.v1       helm.sh/release.v1                    1      16h
sh.helm.release.v1.zeppelin.v1    helm.sh/release.v1                    1      18h
sh.helm.release.v1.zookeeper.v1   helm.sh/release.v1                    1      16h
spark-secret                      Opaque                                0      16h
zeppelin-dockercfg-7zdkm          kubernetes.io/dockercfg               1      18h
zeppelin-token-85jtc              kubernetes.io/service-account-token   4      18h
zeppelin-token-x4r5c              kubernetes.io/service-account-token   4      18h
```

Comment: Have you checked the answers? They helped you solving your problem? If yes, please consider to [accept and upvote](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) it.

Answer (score 2):

`kubectl get secrets` will list secrets from `default` namespace unless you have set a namespace context for the current cluster in your kubeconfig file.

`kubectl get secrets -n iotdevadm` to list secrets from `iotdevadm` namespace.

Answer (score 0):

The commands that you are running are different- one has get and the other one has list.

```
kubectl get secrets
```

Above command will get secrets in the namespace configured in kubeconfig. I assume the namespace is `iotdevadm` in kubeconfig. If this is not the case then run below command.

```
kubectl get secrets -n iotdevadm
```

The equivalent command to check permission should be as below.

```
kubectl auth can-i get secrets --namespace iotdevadm
```

This command will check permission to get secrets for the user configured in kubeconfig in namespace `iotdevadm`.

Answer (score 0):

Let's say we have namespace **testns** and service account **testsa** created in this namespace **testns**. If you try `kubectl auth can-i ...` as follows, you should have:

```
$ kubectl auth can-i get pods --as=system:serviceaccount:testns:testsa -n testns
no

$ kubectl auth can-i get secrets --as=system:serviceaccount:testns:testsa -n testns
no
```

Let's say now that you have a role allowing listing of pods but no rights specified for secrets on it. As soon as you bind this role with service account **testsa** in namespace **testns**, you should have something like this:

```
$ kubectl auth can-i get pods --as=system:serviceaccount:testns:testsa -n testns
yes

$ kubectl auth can-i get secrets --as=system:serviceaccount:testns:testsa -n testns
no
```